# Python : Dictionary with one key and multiple values : How to get list of keys having same SET of values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary :

```
MPO       -  GSTM1 FINC ELN

HMOX1     -  GSTM1 ELN CAV1

POLD1     -  GSTM1 FINC ELN

MAPK1     -  FINC ELN CAV1

VCAM1     -  FINC ELN CAV1

CTGF      -  FINC ELN CAV1

DECR1     -  GSTM1 ELN CAV1
```

i.e one key with multiple values.. I need to sort the key with respect to the SET of values and get the result as follows.

```
GSTM1 FINC ELN   -->   MPO , POLD1

GSTM1 ELN CAV1   -->   HMOX1 , DECR1

FINC ELN CAV1   -->   MAPK1 , VCAM1 , CTGF
```

I need to find the keys having same set of values. I am a beginner in Python and ve no idea how to start .. Need help !!

Comment: You have a list of text, could you please reformat to actual python data structures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dic = {}

dic['MPO']= 'GSTM1 FINC ELN'

dic['HMOX1'] = 'GSTM1 ELN CAV1'

dic['POLD1'] = 'GSTM1 FINC ELN'

dic['MAPK1'] = 'FINC ELN CAV1'

dic['VCAM1'] = 'FINC ELN CAV1'

dic['CTGF']= 'FINC ELN CAV1'

dic['DECR1'] = 'GSTM1 ELN CAV1'

keys = dic.keys()
values = set(dic.values())

for value in values:
    allkeys = ''
    for key in keys:
        if dic[key] == value:
            allkeys = allkeys +" "+str(key)+","
    print value ,'--->', allkeys
```

output:

```
GSTM1 ELN CAV1 --->  HMOX1, DECR1,
GSTM1 FINC ELN --->  MPO, POLD1,
FINC ELN CAV1 --->  CTGF, MAPK1, VCAM1,
```

Comment: Just want i needed .. Thank u so much !!

Answer (score 1):

If you have built this dict, you can keep another dictionary from this dictionary's values to a list of this dict keys. If this dictionary is inputed as is, you will have to iterate over the values and build the reverse dict/set to answer this kind of query.

Answer (score -1):

here you are (the code below suppose values are already a list of strings) :

```
# a special dict that will create a default value for each key, in this case a list
inversed_dict = defaultdict(list) 
#loop over the key, values couples
for key, values in mydict.iteritem(): 
        #turn values into a tuple, which is immutable, and therefore can be a key in a dict
        values = tuple(values) 
        # use the value as key, and append the former key to the lsit (default value of the defaultdict)
        inversed_dict[values].append(key)
```